# Can every cancellative invertible-free monoid be embedded in a group?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

A monoid is *invertible-free* if $xy=1$ implies $x=y=1$ for all $x,y$.

Question: Can every cancellative invertible-free monoid be embedded in a group?

I'm fairly sure that a quotient of the free product of such a monoid with its mirror (this is the monoid with the same elements and identity but reversed multiplication, i.e. $x\cdot y=yx$) is the "most general" group in which it can be embedded.

This is the non-commutative version of the construction of the integers from the natural numbers.

Does this appear anywhere in the literature as a problem / proposition / theorem?

Comment: No, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109566/ and references therein.

Comment: To add detail to @SalvoTringali's answer Malcev gave  the first example of a cancelative monoid not embeddable in a group and if is given by a finite presentation where both sides of each relation have length 2.  So two equivalent words have the sam length and so if is invertible free

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not true even for finitely generated monoids. Take any semigroup $S$ which is cancellative and does not embed into a group (first examples were constructed by Malcev). Consider the monoid $S^1$ which is $S\sqcup\{1\}$ with $1$ a (new if $S$ is a monoid) neutral element.  Then $S^1$ is an invertible-free  monoid which does not embed into a group. It is cancellative iff $S$ does not have a neutral element.

Comment: This was the answer given in the comments

Comment: If you mean your comment, then it is clearly different.

Comment: How? Malcev gives a presentation in which all relations have both sides of length 2. It can be interpret as a monoid presentation or a semigroup presentation.  I interpret it as a monoid presentation and hence get exactly what you get by interpreting it as a semigroup adjoining an identity. So it is the same monoid

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg dodd’s answer applies to *any* cancellative groupoid that does not embed into a group, it does not rely on the specifics of Malcev’s construction.

Comment: @EmilJerabek I guess this depends perspective.  My answer is that Malcev's example has no units because his construction doesn't have the empty word in the relations.  That is the same as adjoining and identify

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg That’s my point. You are saying something about a specific property of a specific example by Malcev, whereas dodd presents a general construction.

Comment: But is $S^1$ cancellative?

Comment: In any case, MO works best if questions are answered with an answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov As mentioned in dodd's answer, $S^1$ is cancellative iff $S$ doesn't already have an identity. Assume $xy = xz$ for some $x, y, z \in S^1$ with $y \ne z$ (the case where $yx = zx$ is similar). Since $S$ is cancellative, this is only possible if, say, $z = 1$ and $x, y \in S$. It follows that $xyv = xv$ and, hence, $yv = v$ for every $v \in S$ (here we use that $x$, $y$, and $v$ are all in $S$ and $S$ is cancellative). But this implies that, for each $v \in S$, $vyv = v^2$ and, hence, $vy = v$. So, $S$ is a monoid and $y$ is its identity.